# How to send info to LCD from web

Tags: php, visual-studio, flexbuilder, lcd

I have seen applications capable of sending information to Logitech LCD panels and played with that a bit a few years ago.  Currently, I have four small LCD panels.  Two are CrystalFontz 633s, one came from a 1U EMC data storage box and one was taken from an old ethernet-based KVM, so I've no idea what it's capabilities are.  Using either Flex Builder or Visual Studio, is it possible to create either a webpage or an offline app, such as for Adobe Air, Mac Widget, or Windows 7 Gadget, that can check for and feed text to a USB- or serial-connected LCD device?  If it's an offline app, it would be very convenient to be able to talk to web-based php scripts and relay that data back to the LCD.

Comment: Why not hook them up to a server computer (Linux), which starts a browser on a particular page in full screen mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can talk to serial ports and fortunately for you someone has done the heavy lifting already:

`http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/`

After that it's just a question of talking to the LCD with whatever set of instructions it understands. That information should be in the developer manual unless you want to go the fun route and send random characters until something happens :)

Comment: Awesome, that may just do it.  I have two 633s, one serial and one USB and the USB basially emulates a serial port anyway.  The test software from CrystalFontz gives a readout of the commands used to send characters to the screen, so that's easy enough to get.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write directly to LCD's. That's just pain. Instead, write a tiny client application that will talk to your web server, and display the data on your LCD screens.